# Add a Custom Validator globally, to all FormControls in the application

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

We have a client who came up with the idea of adding a custom validator to EVERY field in their application, which contains over 1000 Angular formControls.

My question is: is there a way to globally modify the behavior of all `formControls` without manually and individually adding this validator to each of the thousand formControls?

- Writing a custom validator works, but adding it manually  `myField: ['', [Validators.required, mySpecialValidator]]` is quite the tedious task which we want to avoid.
- ChatGPT suggested writing a directive and applying it to the HTML template, but I'm in the same situation as before; I still need to modify a thousand input fields. Is there a library or trick that allows for global modification of the behavior of all formControls?

Comment: May be add custom validator to each form (not each form control) I am sure you wont have too much forms :)

Comment: @KamranKhatti that is a good advice, thank you. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Please consider voting on this question if you find it a good one so others may see it too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to define a global validators for each form control, however we can add a custom validator on each form (not form control).

This approach is less hectic than adding validation on each form control, controls can be 1000 but form could be fewer so I would go with [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) on each form.

```
const myForm = new FormGroup({
 'myField': new FormControl(),
 ...
}, { validators: mySpecialValidator });
```

Hope this address your issue.